# mkvirtualenv running without error but not creating the environment in zsh

Tags: python, virtualenv, zsh, virtualenvwrapper

I'm transitioning to zsh on my Mac (Catalina). So far so good except my virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper aren't working as expected. I've tried re installation with the following steps:

```
rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs  # Delete all existing data.
pip uninstall virtualenv virtualenvwrapper # Remove
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper # Reinstall
```

Added following lines to ~/.zshrc

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7
export WORKON_HOME="${HOME}/.virtualenvs"
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

I now have access to the commands in zsh. but if I try to make an env with:
`mkvirtualenv testenv`
I get:

```
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/alesirowland/.virtualenvs/bin/python3.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/alesirowland/.virtualenvs/bin/python (you must use /Users/alesirowland/.virtualenvs/bin/python3.7)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

running `lsvirtualenv` returns no environments. It also appears to be trying to use 3.7 despite my environment variables written to default to python2.7. Going back into my bash console creates the env but also defaults to python3. What have I got wrong?

EDITs:
verbose output is generally asking to install in ~/.virtualenvs/bin rather than ~/.virtualenvs//bin
workon on an existing env just echos all of my envs to the screen.

Comment: Tip: you can just write `source =virtualenvwrapper.sh` instead of calling `which` explicitly.

Comment: Also, did you source `.zshrc` after editing it? It's also better practice to put modifications to your environment in `.zprofile`, as they can be inherited by child shells rather than needing to be explicitly (re)set in `.zshrc` each time.

Comment: I did source .zshrc after editing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! this line in my .zshrc is affecting virtualenvwrapper for some reason `setopt KSHARRAYS`